# Barcode Scanner in excel

Tags: excel, barcode-scanner, vba

Right now I have a spreadsheet in excel with some vba in it to use as an inventory database for our small business. The problem is that we are growing and I need to get more sophisticated.

The scanner is used with a Userform with a textbox control monitoring the number of characters that come into the textbox. When the specified number of characters is triggered the system does its job. What I need to accomplish is a way to monitor the input coming from the scanner itself without using a textbox control so that I can set up multiple scanners without them interfering with one another.

Any direction on this is greatly appreciated.

Here is the code:

```
Private Sub TextBox1_Change()
On Error GoTo endgame

Dim barCode As String
Dim charNumb As Long

    barCode = TextBox1.Text
    charNumb = Len(barCode)

    'This triggers the system to perform actions based on the barcode number   
    'received. All of my barcodes for this version are formatted to have only 5
    'characters. Works great with a single user and scanner.

    If charNumb = 5 Then

        Cells.Find(barCode).Activate
        ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Activate
        ActiveCell = ActiveCell + 1
        ActiveCell.Offset(0, 17).Activate
        ActiveCell = ActiveCell + 1

        If ActiveCell = ActiveCell.Offset(0, -1) Then

            ActiveCell.Offset(0, -1).Clear
            ActiveCell.Clear

            GoTo TIMESTAMPER

        Else
            GoTo TIMESTAMPER
        End If

        TIMESTAMPER:
        TextBox1.Text = ""

        'Timestamp
        ActiveCell.Offset(0, -5).Activate

        With ActiveCell
          .Formula = Now
          .NumberFormat = "m/d/yyyy h:mm:ss AM/PM"
        End With

        ActiveWorkbook.Save
        ActiveCell.EntireRow.Select
        TextBox1.SetFocus
    End If

    GoTo AllEndsWell

    endgame:

    Call errorsound

    AllEndsWell:

End Sub
```

Comment: The scanner is coming in via USB.

Comment: Please post the code that is currently "receiving" the scanner input and putting it in the textbox.  We can then help you take the textbox out of the equation.

Comment: That only shows what is happening when the textbox changes, not how the textbox is being changed.  Should I assume the scanner software is writing the value into the textbox?  If so that is how that software is coded to do it and you probably can't change that.

Comment: One more comment: If your scanner is writing this data to a form in a spreadsheet and then you are using that event to add the time to the spreadsheet, you can't have more than one person scanning at the same time because the spreadsheet can only be opened in write mode by one user.  You probably need to move up to an Access database.  The scanner may have an option for that.

Comment: The scanner is operating like a keyboard with the characters contained in the barcode. When I scan the barcode it inputs the 5 characters into the textbox. Since this macro is initialized every time the text in the textbox changes it runs the code when the number of Characters is equal to 5. I could put the barcode numbers in with a regular keyboard or with the scanner either one. The problems arise when I have two scanners scan simultaneously. The barcodes intertwine and cause an error because the 5 characters they generate are not in the spreadsheet.

Comment: If it is the same as keyboard input, even with multiple textboxes or multiple forms, the text is going to go to the control that has focus. I can't think of anyway to control where the text will go.  There might be an answer out there but I can't think of it.  If your question doesn't get anymore attention, post it on SO again later with your code and include the info from our comments.

Comment: Update, I moved all of this over to access a long time ago. Works much better in there.

Answer (score 1):

I have previously attempted to add barcode reader support to Excel and while the following has not been fully tested, I recall it was working; however there are some requirements to make it work

Within the code to follow, a barcode read is performed when a system message has been 'peaked' at and starts with a specific character. Most barcode readers can be programmed to output text in a certain way; the code requires an invisible precursor to be added to strings which is detected via msgMessage.wParam (Code example Case 17) and an enter character to follow the string to show when the barcode read is complete and reset the listener

For your barcode readers you may need to alter which character is prefixed and it's associated detection character (Ascii value. i.e. 17)

My current code:

The following code should be placed in a Class Module 'KeyPressApi'

```
Option Explicit

Private Type BARCODEBUFFER
    strBuf As String
    bCode As Boolean
End Type

Private Type POINTAPI
    x As Long
    y As Long
End Type

Private Type MSG
    hwnd As Long
    Message As Long
    wParam As Long
    lParam As Long
    time As Long
    pt As POINTAPI
End Type

Private Declare Function WaitMessage Lib "user32" () As Long

Private Declare Function PeekMessage Lib "user32" Alias "PeekMessageA" _
    (ByRef lpMsg As MSG, ByVal hwnd As Long, _
     ByVal wMsgFilterMin As Long, _
     ByVal wMsgFilterMax As Long, _
     ByVal wRemoveMsg As Long) As Long

Private Declare Function TranslateMessage Lib "user32" _
    (ByRef lpMsg As MSG) As Long

Private Declare Function PostMessage Lib "user32" Alias "PostMessageA" _
    (ByVal hwnd As Long, _
     ByVal wMsg As Long, _
     ByVal wParam As Long, _
     lParam As Any) As Long

Private Declare Function FindWindow Lib "user32" Alias "FindWindowA" _
    (ByVal lpClassName As String, _
     ByVal lpWindowName As String) As Long

Private Const WM_KEYDOWN As Long = &H100
Private Const PM_REMOVE  As Long = &H1
Private Const WM_CHAR    As Long = &H102
Private bExitLoop As Boolean
Private bufBuffer As BARCODEBUFFER

Public Event BarcodeRead(Barcode As String, ByRef Cancel As Boolean)

Public Sub StartKeyPressInit()
    Dim msgMessage As MSG
    Dim bCancel As Boolean
    Dim iMessage As Integer
    Dim iKeyCode As Integer
    Dim lXLhwnd As Long

    On Error GoTo errHandler
    Application.EnableCancelKey = xlErrorHandler
    bExitLoop = False 'Initialize boolean flag.
    lXLhwnd = FindWindow("XLMAIN", Application.Caption) 'Get the app hwnd.

    Do
        WaitMessage 'check for a key press and remove it from the msg queue.
        If PeekMessage(msgMessage, lXLhwnd, WM_KEYDOWN, WM_KEYDOWN, PM_REMOVE) Then
            iKeyCode = msgMessage.wParam 'store the virtual key code for later use.
            iMessage = msgMessage.Message

            TranslateMessage msgMessage 'translate the virtual key code into a char msg.
            PeekMessage msgMessage, lXLhwnd, WM_CHAR, WM_CHAR, PM_REMOVE

            bCancel = False
            Select Case iKeyCode 'Enter and backspace not handled correctly by below case statement
                Case 8 ' Backspace
                    If bufBuffer.bCode = True Then
                        If Len(bufBuffer.strBuf) > 0 Then
                            bufBuffer.strBuf = Left(bufBuffer.strBuf, Len(bufBuffer.strBuf) - 1)
                            bCancel = True
                        End If
                    End If
                Case 13 ' End of barcode string so reset to off mode
                    If bufBuffer.bCode = True Then
                        bufBuffer.bCode = False
                        RaiseEvent BarcodeRead(ReadBuffer(), 0)
                        bCancel = True
                    End If
                Case Else
            End Select

            Select Case msgMessage.wParam
                Case 17 ' Start of Barcode; Initialize buffer array
                    If bufBuffer.bCode = False Then
                        bufBuffer.bCode = True
                        bufBuffer.strBuf = ""
                        bCancel = True
                    End If
                Case Else ' All other data
                    If bufBuffer.bCode = True Then
                        If iKeyCode <> 0 Then
                            bufBuffer.strBuf = bufBuffer.strBuf & Chr(msgMessage.wParam)
                            bCancel = True
                        End If
                    End If
            End Select

            'if the key pressed is allowed post it to the application.
            If Not bCancel Then PostMessage lXLhwnd, iMessage, iKeyCode, 0
        End If

errHandler:     'Allow the processing of other msgs.
        DoEvents
    Loop Until bExitLoop
End Sub

Public Sub StopKeyPressWatch()
    bExitLoop = True 'Set this boolean flag to exit the above loop.
End Sub

Public Function ReadBuffer() As String
    ReadBuffer = bufBuffer.strBuf
    Dim i As Integer
    For i = 1 To 31
        ReadBuffer = Replace(ReadBuffer, Chr(i), "")
    Next
End Function
```

Then within the sheet that you want to override the listener

```
Option Explicit

Dim WithEvents CKeyWatcher As KeyPressApi

Private Sub Worksheet_Activate()
    If CKeyWatcher Is Nothing Then Set CKeyWatcher = New KeyPressApi
    If Not CKeyWatcher Is Nothing Then CKeyWatcher.StartKeyPressInit
End Sub

Private Sub Worksheet_Deactivate()
    If Not CKeyWatcher Is Nothing Then CKeyWatcher.StopKeyPressWatch
End Sub

Private Sub CKeyWatcher_BarcodeRead(strBuffer As String, Cancel As Boolean)
    MsgBox strBuffer
End Sub
```

Comment: There is a lot of new in this code. I will let you know if it worked since I a below a 15 on the reputation counter right now. Thank you for the .edu